# Jenkins returns 502 gateway error and (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: jenkins, nginx

So my server got maintenance schedule from cloud provider, after maintenance process, the server rebooted, then my jenkins cannot be accessed from the web anymore, I am using nginx and checking the logs I found this.

> /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2018/03/26 16:11:00 [error] 21689#21689: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 139.139.139.139, server: jenkins.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "jenkins.domain.com"

2018/03/26 16:11:00 [error] 21689#21689: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 139.139.139.139, server: jenkins.domain.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "jenkins.domain.com", referrer: "http://jenkins.domain.com/"
```

here is my nginx conf file:

```
upstream app_server {
server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}



server {
  listen 80;
  server_name jenkins.domain.com;
  root /var/www/jenkins.domain.com;

  location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
        default_type "text/plain";
  }

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this and maybe what can I do to fix this? Really need your help guys.

Thanks

Comment: Got same problem. Did you find a solution? I tried already most of the stuff that come up on google, but still struggling

Comment: @Lukino did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @FooBar Hmm, it is a while, but I managed to get my Jenkins running behind Nginx. (to be a little bit more specific, I got Nginx, Jenkins and Nexus running as Docker containers on the Physical server...

Answer (score 2):

If the system recently rebooted and your proxy server is giving 502/503s, it's most likely that the backend service failed to start.

Using whatever tools are most appropriate for your OS/distro (e.g. `systemctl`, `service`/`chkconfig`, `stop`/`start`/`restart`/etc.), do the following things:

- Verify that the backend (in this case Jenkins) is configured to start on boot.  Enable it if not.
- Start the backend.
- If the backend fails to start, check the application logs to find the source of the error.  For Jenkins on Linux, this would be `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`.

Comment: All the services, nginx and jenkins are up and running, jenkins is started on boot, but still I got the same errors.

Comment: same here, i know it's been a long time since this has been posted, but have you found the solution?

Comment: @JosephK. did you find a solution?